# How to implement an online audio library (store audio in database or file)

Tags: database, web-applications, audio

Can anyone shed some light on how to implement an online audio library? In my project, the audio files will be wav files, and they are short in length (a few seconds max). Should I put them into the database or just leave them in the file system?

I'm thinking when I play them back in the browser, I have to write them in a file anyway. If I'm using database, is the overhead too much?

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you want to do with the wav files. For instance, if you want to copy and paste them into another folder, this is alot more difficult if you save the .wav files as blobs.

Also, if your looking at getting bigger, and using something like s3, its easier to migrate to s3 from an existing folder rather than extracting the blobs.

Storing as blobs will also effect your database backups, where each backup will include all .wav files which you might not necessarily need. But it does give you good scope to query details of the file, but this can be replicated by storing a filepath rather than the file itself. Just my two cents :)